# About popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I want to get a popup window which appears after pressing a button.
Most important is in popup window there should be (stars/radio buttons) to take ratings, and there are two more buttons to go further different links.

Comment: Popups are bad practice, since you tagged jquery, you should see https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to open dialog box or popup window using jQuery, then you can use jQuery dialog for this. Along with this code, you have to include jQuery and jQuery-UI files.

Here is the code to implement jQuery Dialog.

Add following CSS Code for jQuery Dialog box within `<Style>` tags

```
 <style>
     .ui-widget-header,.ui-state-default, ui-button {
        background:#b9cd6d;
        border: 1px solid #b9cd6d;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-weight: bold;
     }
  </style>
```

Add following HTML tag within `<body>` tags

```
<div id = "dialog-1" 
    title = "Dialog Title goes here...">This my first jQuery UI Dialog!</div>
<button id = "opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

Add following script within `<script>` tags

```
  <script>
     $(function() {
        $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog({
           autoOpen: false,  
        });
        $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
           $( "#dialog-1" ).dialog( "open" );
        });
     });
  </script>
```